# Mock a method of a mocked object in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking

I am writing unit tests for a project written in Python 3.4, using the `unittest.mock` library. The function I am testing contains a call to a function

```
versions = get_all_versions(some_argument)
```

which I have patched with a `MagicMock` object that returns a list, so that `version` becomes a list of version numbers, which all works fine.

Now, the code I am testing has changed a bit, and looks like

```
versions = get_all_versions(some_argument).order_by(another_argument)
```

Now I need the `order_by` method to return the same list of version numbers, while `get_all_versions` should remain mocked, and I have some problems achieving this.

I have tried patching it with

```
get_all_versions = MagicMock()
get_all_versions.order_by = version_list
```

but that does not work, and I guess it is because `order_by` is a method and not a property. I have also tried

```
get_all_versions = MagicMock()
get_all_versions.order_by = MagicMock(return_value=version_list)
```

and (more desperately)

```
get_all_versions = MagicMock(return_value=MagicMock(return_value=version_list))
```

but neither of those two work.

How do I mock a function that returns an object, and then mock a method of that object so that it returns a list?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

What you want is to have `get_all_versions` return an object that has a method `order_by` which returns `version_list`:

```
get_all_versions = MagicMock()
get_all_versions.return_value.order_by.return_value = version_list
```

---

To explain why your attempts didn't work, your first attempt replaces the method `order_by` with the value `version_list`:

```
get_all_versions = MagicMock()
get_all_versions.order_by = version_list
```

The result of this is roughly this:

```
get_all_versions.order_by == version_list
```

---

The second attempt replaces the return value of `get_all_versions` with something that looks like a function and returns `version_list`:

```
get_all_versions = MagicMock(return_value=MagicMock(return_value=version_list))
```

This results in:

```
get_all_versions(some_argument)(another_argument) == version_list
```

I hope this clears things up!

Comment: wow, this is a hard thing to figure out by yourself, thank you

Comment: Exactly!! @sleepyhead